# Custom styling on sharepoint.com

Tags: css

Is there any way to override styles for a sharepoint.com site?

For example, I want `H3` elements to be the same color as the `H2` elements.

I've seen threads about how to do this for a site sitting on an accessible server, but nothing for the hosted solution.

Comment: Can you manipulate the master page? If so, just load your custom CSS file after all the other CSS files in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Add a content editor web part on your page.

Click Format Text -> Edit Source

```
<h1>​​​This is ​heading 1</h1> 
<h2>​This is heading 2​<br/></h2> 
<h3>This is heading 3</h3> 
<style>
h3 { color: red }
</style>​​​
```

You can change the style of your H3 elements to be any color you want. This will only affect the elements on the current page but it is pretty easy to do.